# List of deleted and modified instances of recurring meeting

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

How to get the full list of deleted and/or modified instances of recurring meeting using Google Calendar API v3?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `showDeleted` and `singleEvents` properties of [`Events.list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

`showDeleted` includes deleted events in the result of `Events.list`.

> **showDeleted** - boolean
>
> Whether to include deleted events (with **status** equals "**cancelled**") in
>   the result. Cancelled instances of recurring events (but not the
>   underlying recurring event) will still be included if **showDeleted** and
>   **singleEvents** are both False. If **showDeleted** and **singleEvents** are both
>   True, only single instances of deleted events (but not the underlying
>   recurring events) are returned. Optional. The default is False.

`singleEvents` determines if the events to show are recurring or not.

> **singleEvents** - boolean
>
> Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return
>   single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the
>   underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is
>   False.

You can try it [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it).

Comment: Oh, so you are suggesting to put ICalID to the request and that would return all exceptions and deleted instances for the recurring meeting?